# TeamCity 8 support for SVN 1.8?

Tags: svn, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I'm using TeamCity 8.0.3 (build 27540), the latest as of this post. It only supports up to SVN 1.7 but my SVN server is at 1.8.

Is there anything I can do to make TeamCity support SVN 1.8? I'd prefer not to have to downgrade my SVN server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just tested out this using Teamcity 8.0.2 and subversion 1.8.3. They're working together without any issue.

Both server side and agent side checkout work, however, if you're planning to use any new 1.8 based features (agent-side checkouts) that requires a client that is minimum 1.8 in version, you have a problem, since teamcity uses a java library for svn operations (svnkit), and the latest bundled lib supports 1.7 and lower working copy versions.

See this feature matrix: http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html

If you don't need 'working copy record moves', 'automatic reintegration merge' or any other feature where the minimum client is 1.8, you're good to go.

Comment: Lack of support for SVN 1.8 working copies is a show stopper in our environment. The Visual Studio add-in refuses to use the 1.8 release of the SVN client. Hope this gets fixed soon.

Comment: How is Visual Studio linked to Team City in this regard?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're using `file:///` protocol, it doesn't matter what version your SVN server has, because SVN servers and SVN/SVNKit clients are forward and backward compatible with all versions of SVN servers. In particular, you can use SVN/SVNKit of version 1.7 with mod_dav_svn/svnserve of version1.8.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the official support page for Subversion 1.8 support in TeamCity: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/TeamCity+Subversion+1.8+support